# Revisions to Catholic Bible (NABRE) in Psalm 23:1

Tags: psalms, word-study

Our missalettes use New American Revised Edition (NABRE). Today's mass included Psalm 23.  In v.1, there is a  change from what I learned (whether from KJV or NASB or Douay-Rheims).

Ps. 23:1:

> The Lord is my shepherd;
>   there is nothing I lack. ([NABRE](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+23%3A1&version=NABRE))
>
> The Lord is my shepherd,
>   I shall not want. ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+23%3A1&version=NASB))

Questions: If there is a difference in meaning between these, which is closer to the original?  What is the reason for the change?

Comment: Hello, and welcome. We're happy to help with this sort of thing. However, these are two separate questions about translations of different texts by different authors in different languages. Please ask them as separate questions. You can [edit this one](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/13731/edit) to narrow it down to one and then open a new question for the other.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it. I just made a few small formatting changes. If you look at the "edit" view you can see how we format quotes. Just makes for a little easier reading. (Also, [signing posts is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/272257) since they are linked directly to your profile.)

Comment: Lack and want mean the same thing. But the change from the future to present tense is uncalled for. It should be "I will not lack" or "I shall not lack."  "There is nothing I lack" is just dumbed down, which is how the NABRE is everywhere, dumbed down to the point of being pretty well intended for illiterates.  Apparently the Catholic hierarchy thinks you're stupid.

Answer (score 3):

Both translations are suitable! But they indicate the original Hebrew has a deeper meaning than can be conveyed in one sentence of English. The two main issues here is the meaning of the word "lack" and how to best translate that from the imperfective. The details:

The first verse contains four Hebrew words, two phrases of two words each. The first says simply: "Yahweh [is] my-shepherd".

The second phrase is: "Not I-lack". The first word לֹא is a simple negation. The second word אֶחְסָר is a verb. The first letter (on the right) א is the sign for first common singular "I". This leaves us with the root word חסר. Glosses for this word include "decrease", "be devoid of", "lack", in other words, to "be in want of." :)

This verb is in the imperfective, which means it's not in the perfective form, not that it's imperfect. The imperfective in Hebrew can mean anything from an ongoing incomplete action to a future completed action.

It looks like חסר is a stative verb. Stative verbs tend to become active in the imperfective and take a future meaning.[1] This implies then a translation of: "I will not become lacking" which reads poorly in English. A smoother translation (lacking the active tense): "I will never be in need."

Remember to check any interpretation/application with other passages, including James 4:2-3.

[edit: misc updates, thanks Davïd]

[1] J/M §113a

Comment: Note: "`לֹא however, [with] the imperfective always means a permanent prohibition`" - when used with the 2nd person (that's what makes it an "injunction" of some kind). Here, with the first person, it's just a simple negation.

Comment: Then I think NASB is better, as it is forward looking. Still wondering why the NABRE focuses on the present and uses a transitive verb, which is so different from the intransitive (my English grammar).  Thank you for the insights.